# Building an Autonomous Number System web scraper /How to extract numbers from a text file

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, text-files

I'm trying to build a web **scraper** with javascript using node packages to get asn prefix data from this web site: http://bgp.he.net/AS2#_prefixes .

This is what I have so far:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

apnList = {
    'MIT': 3,
    'Dynamics': 15,
    'NYU': 12,
    'Harvard': 11,
    'Bull HN Information Sys': 6,
    'NNIC': 22,
    'Symbolics': 5,
    'University of Delaware': 2
};
for (apn in apnList) {
    var url = 'http://bgp.he.net/AS'+apnList[apn]+'#_prefixes'


    request(url,  (function(apn) { return function(err, resp, body) {
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        console.log(body) 
            
    }})(apn));
}
```

When I run the file in the terminal I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /AS11
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at bgp.he.net Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

For each number. How do I fix that?

Also, bonus question:  In the end I want to take every asn number from this txt file and feed it into the for loop.

```
[asn.txt]                                        2014-06-30 02:05:03Z

This file contains a list of autonomous system numbers and names of all
registered ASNs.  The column on the right below contains the ARIN
database "handle" of the technical, abuse or NOC contacts for the ASN.
Additional information may be obtained about any of the ASN contacts
in this list by querying the ARIN WHOIS server.  For questions or updates
on this information please contact the ARIN Registration Services Hostmaster
staff, HOSTMASTER@ARIN.NET.

AS Number               AS Name                                            POC Handles
 0                       IANA-RSVD-0                                        IANA-IP-ARIN (Abuse), IANA-ARIN (Admin), IANA-IP-ARIN (Tech)
 1                       LVLT-1                                             IPADD5-ARIN (Tech), APL8-ARIN (Abuse), NOCSU27-ARIN (NOC), APL7-ARIN (Admin)
 2                       UDEL-DCN                                           CASHJ-ARIN (Tech), NSS13-ARIN (Abuse), DJG2-ARIN (Tech), DJG2-ARIN (Admin)
 3                       MIT-GATEWAYS                                       MNO78-ARIN (NOC), SILIS-ARIN (Admin), MNS18-ARIN (Abuse), SILIS-ARIN (Tech)
 4                       ISI-AS                                             ACT-ORG-ARIN (Admin), ACT-ORG-ARIN (Abuse), ACT-ORG-ARIN (Tech)
 5                       SYMBOLICS                                          SG52-ARIN (Tech), SG52-ARIN (Admin), SG52-ARIN (Abuse)
 6                       BULL-HN                                            USINT-ARIN (Admin), ZB126-ARIN (Abuse), ZB126-ARIN (Tech), JLM23-ARIN (Tech)
 7                       RIPE-ASNBLOCK-7                                    ABUSE3850-ARIN (Abuse), RNO29-ARIN (Tech), RNO29-ARIN (Admin)
 8                       RICE-AS                                            RUH-ORG-ARIN (Tech), RUH-ORG-ARIN (Admin), RUH-ORG-ARIN (Abuse)
 9                       CMU-ROUTER                                         CH4-ORG-ARIN (Tech), CH4-ORG-ARIN (NOC), CMA3-ARIN (Abuse), CH4-ORG-ARIN (Admin)
 10                      CSNET-EXT-AS                                       CS15-ARIN (Abuse), CS15-ARIN (Tech), CS15-ARIN (Admin)
 11                      HARVARD                                            JNL17-ARIN (Admin), JNL17-ARIN (Tech
```

That was just a snippet of it.  It goes on for many thousands of numbers.  Is there anyway to selectively extract each number from the AS number column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to come back and answer this.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs= require('fs')
var filename="/scraping/asn.txt "

apnList = {
    'MIT': 3,
    'Dynamics': 15,
    'NYU': 12,
    'Harvard': 11,
    'Bull HN Information Sys': 6,
    'NNIC': 22,
    'Symbolics': 5,
    'University of Delaware': 2
};
for (apn in apnList) {
    var options = {
        url : 'http://bgp.he.net/AS'+apnList[apn]+'#_prefixes',
        headers:  {
            'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36'
        }
    };


    request(options,  (function(apn) { return function(err, resp, body) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('#table_prefixes4 tr').each(function(index, prefix) {

            $(this).find('.nowrap').each(function(){
            event = $(this).text().trim();
            nextevent = $(this).next().text();
            console.log(apn+","+event+","+nextevent)
            });        
        });


    }})(apn));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems bgp.he.net blocks attempts to scrape its site, possibly based on user agent. That's why you're getting the 403 error: access is denied! You could try changing the user agent that Node.js uses when retrieving remote URLs (not sure how to do that offhand though), but it seems Hurricane Electric isn't a fan of scraping, so you should probably avoid it.

Comment: Forgot to come back and answer this.  Yeah the options object allows you to pass in a header.